# How to have trailing zero in CSV

Tags: linux, csv, sendmail

The following is the sample csv file:

```
12354506.0,4
13129229.0,4
815612,5
7624107.0,5
6056548.0,5
```

The trailing zero in the first column is formatted to hole number on CSV VIEWER.

Is there any option to have trailing zero?

I was able to have trailing zero by prefix single quotes to the first column. But it looks odd with single quotes.

```
'12354506.0,4
'13129229.0,4
'815612,5
'7624107.0,5
'6056548.0,5
```

Comment: This is likely a feature of your CSV viewer software (you don't mention what the software is). It may have the option to show a configurable number of decimal places for numeric data.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, we can configure the decimal places, but it create a conflict in 3rd row of  my input file since it  doesn't have decimal value.

Comment: Why is this tagged sendmail?

Answer (score 0):

It's purely behavior of CVS viewer which you are using. I'm able to replicate the same issue with MS Excel.

```
awk -F "," '{print "=\""$1"\","$2}' test.csv > test3.csv
```

- `=` will force the data to be text.

To edit the file.

```
echo "$(awk -F "," '{print "=\""$1"\","$2}' test.csv)" > test.csv
```

Comment: Is it possible to edit the file, in spite of creating the new file...

Comment: @ababkren try the second code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the CSV viewer software seems to be able to detect floating point numbers by the inclusion of a fractional part, the numbers must be converted to have at least one decimal.

One way of doing this with `awk`:

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," '$1 == int($1) { $1 = sprintf("%.1f", $1) } 1' file >newfile
```

This would test the first comma-separated field to see if it was a whole number.  In that case, it would rewrite the field as `n.0` (where `n` is the original number).  The trailing `1` in the code would cause all lines to be outputted.

The result in written to the new file `newfile`.

A similar solution using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]*\),/\1.0,/' file >newfile
```

Here, we match any number of digits followed immediately by a comma, and replace that with the same digits, `.0`, and the comma.  This would ignore the numbers that already have fractional parts, but would add `.0` to numbers that don't have that.

Answer (score 0):

with reference to the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458763/294759).

```
 awk -F ","  'BEGIN {OFS = FS}{$1="=\""$1"\""; print}' test.csv
```

we may not know how many fields in a csv. Its quite difficult to declare each field in to print. So better we can edit the field which is required.